# How to apply multiple conditions (value AND font color) within a Javascript If statement?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I am new to development and am trying to do something fairly simple. I have a list of travel related transactions in a JSON file and I created a basic grouping of these transactions based on their cost (i.e. if the transactions total less than $300, the travel_rank becomes 'Below Average'). I also want to apply some font conditions as well though. For example, if the travel_rank is 'Below Average', I'd like to color this green (less spending is better). How might I go about doing that? Here is the code I am currently using to identify the rank.

```
let travel_rank = []

if (total_travel_transactions < 300)
{
  travel_rank = 'Below Average'
}
else if (total_travel_transactions > 600)
{
  travel_rank = 'Above Average'
}
else 
  travel_rank = 'Average'
```

An additional question I have is what if I want to create this rank 10x over for other categories such as  entertainment, groceries, dining out, etc. It doesn't seem like the best method is to just copy and paste this code 10x over although perhaps if they all have different input parameters that might make the most sense? Or maybe there's something I can do with list of parameters that I can read in once?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shortened piece of code that would perform your ranking operation on an array of transaction-counts:

```js
const rank=v=>['Below ','','Above '][Math.min(2,Math.floor(v/300))]+'Average';

let transactions=[23,300,567,700,299,600,2000];

 transactions.forEach(t=>console.log(t,rank(t)));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best to organize your data in objects with properties, and not just simple values or arrays. Below you'll find a still quite basic, but working example of doing so, along with how to use CSS for the coloring, and some simple HTML to display it.

I chose to use a table, and half the code is just for dealing with that. There are many other ways, you need to choose what works best for you.

```js
var tableBody = document.getElementById("body_of_table");

var categories = [
   { name: "Travel", amount: 400 },
   { name: "Entertainment", amount: 500 },
   { name: "Groceries", amount: 200 },
   { name: "Dining out", amount: 700 }
];

var descriptions = ["Below average", "Average", "Above average"];

for (var i in categories) {
  var row = tableBody.insertRow(-1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(-1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(-1);
  var category = categories[i];
  var ranking = getRanking(category.amount);
  cell1.textContent = category.name;
  cell2.textContent = category.amount;
  cell3.textContent = ranking + " (" + descriptions[ranking] + ")";
  cell1.className = cell2.className = cell3.className = "ranking" + ranking;
}

function getRanking(amount) {
  if (amount <= 300) return 0;
  if (amount <= 600) return 1;
  return 2;
}
```

```css
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black
}

.ranking0 { background: lightgreen; }
.ranking1 { background: white; }
.ranking2 { background: salmon; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Spending</th>
    <th>Ranking</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="body_of_table">
  </tbody>
</table>
```